# Remote Desktop won't connect between two computers on same VPN, same LAN, when VPN active

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop

If both computers are not connected to the VPN, each can access the other via Remote Desktop over the LAN.

If just one is connected to the VPN, they can't connect -- but I expect that.

If BOTH are connected to the same VPN, however, I'd expect RDP to work over the VPN between the two systems, yet it doesn't.

One possible difference is that one computer is my work laptop, joined to the company domain, and the other is my personal system, which is not on that domain. Could that be important?

Could it be a VPN firewall issue? Window's own VPN isn't blocking RDP traffic, as far as I can tell.

These computers can't ping each other when connected to the VPN either, nor does file sharing function between the two. It's almost as if the VPN functions as a one-way valve, allowing each system to see other resources on the VPN, but without themselves being exposed as available on the VPN.

Comment: "It's almost as if the VPN functions as a one-way valve, allowing each system to see other resources on the VPN, but without themselves being exposed as available on the VPN." - That's it exactly. VPN clients are generally not visible to each other or to other resources on the target network. Each client has a dedicated connection to the VPN server; once connected, they only see what the VPN server is configured to allow them to see.

Comment: Thanks, @pmdba. Can that visibility be changed by the VPN host configuration? (I rather doubt my company's IT folk would be so accommodating if so, but I'm curious anyway.)

Comment: @pmdba... Do you know if RDP can be configured to stay bound to the LAN and ignore the fact that I'm connected to the VPN?

Comment: It would not be RDP that you need to configure. The VPN client *may* have a switch that determines whether it can still see the local network at the same time as the VPN. It very much depends whether your particular VPN client has that option, and if it is provided by your company whether they have locked it down to prevent you changing it. That said, I haven't seen a VPN client with that option enabled in a long, long time. Allowing a VPN client to bridge networks is very insecure; the whole point of the VPN is to prevent a client from being exposed while connected to internal assets.